# ASP.NET: How to add latest news & magazine to the Web Application without writing the Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am developing a web application that enables the admin to add new and newsletter. For adding the news I have a table called news in the database that contains: NewsID, NewsTitle, NewsDescription, Username.
Also, for the newsletter, the admin will upload the ma. For that, I created a table that contains MagazineID, MagazineTitle, Url, Username

By the way, the username column in each one of them is a foreign key to the Users table.

Now I have two questions:
For adding news, I use ListView and everything works fine except for the username column. What I want is just giving the user the ability to fill two columns: NewsTitle and NewsDescription. and his username should be added automatically but how to do that?

For adding news, I am using the following sql commands:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [News] WHERE [NewsID] = @NewsID" 

InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [News] ([NewsTitle], [NewsDesc])
               VALUES (@NewsTitle, @NewsDesc)" 

SelectCommand="SELECT News.NewsID, News.NewsTitle, News.NewsDesc, News.Username
               FROM News
               INNER JOIN employee ON News.Username = employee.Username" 

UpdateCommand="UPDATE [News]
               SET [NewsTitle] = @NewsTitle
                  , [NewsDesc] = @NewsDesc
               WHERE [NewsID] = @NewsID">
```

For the magazine, also, I want to use the ListView and give the user the ability of putting the title and upload the magazine. My question is how to put UploadFile control inside the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

you can set an insert/update parameter value to the Name property of the current HttpContext User property. That value is the the logged in user's username. [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.identity.aspx)

However, usernames may change and you might be better of saving an Id (preferably an int data type) and setting that as a Foreign Key to a user id column in your users table.